# Failed PHP AJAX loading

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hello I am trying to load a php snippet with ajax to my html file.
But for any reason i get this warning:

*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).*

I also tried different types of the url, but nothing seems to help.

This is how my ajax looks like:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("success")
            $('#timestamp').html(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("error");  
        },
 });
```

// I am using Kirby as my cms (maybe it has something to do with it)

Comment: is this ajax call on page with an url not in page root? Then the call goes to ajax.php in that path. Assuming ajax.php is on root level, you can use "/ajax.php" instead of "ajax.php" as url.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. So, my background to use ajax is this: I want to use a datestamp which updates every second, to display the actual time. I've just tried to us "/ajax.php" but i get the same error

Comment: This is just an example / demo right? You're not actually planning on using AJAX to get the time, surely?

Comment: Yes... so i made a quick  fiddle to get a better overview: 
https://jsfiddle.net/okpLLuuv/7/

Comment: I just want to load the php snippet in div and updated the time then